# how show array of textviews in a tableLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, arrays, textview

I have a problem to solve, I have  three array of textviews.

```
- Textview a[];
- TexTview b[];
- TexTview c[]:
```

And I need to display them in a table, like this: [as I need to show it](http://vvcap.net/db/8o24G_xnsT8QRvf5UnI7.htp).
but when the show with the following code, the screen is like this: [so don't need sho like this](http://vvcap.net/db/qWwmyl5SrXLJNFiMnpCy.htp)

```
   ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(a[i]);
   ((ViewGroup)layout).addView(a[i]);
   ((ViewGroup)layout).addView(a[i]);
```

This is the complete code, in advance, thank you very much.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    SitesList sitesList = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /** Create a new layout to display the view */
        View layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

        /** Create a new textview array to display the results */

       TextView variacion[];
       TextView nemotecnico[];
       TextView precio[];

        try {

            /** Handling XML */
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
            URL sourceUrl = new URL("http://www.bovalpo.com/cgi-local/xml_bcv.pl?URL=75");

            /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
            MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
            }

        /** Get result from MyXMLHandler SitlesList Object */
        sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;

        /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
     //   registro = new TextView[sitesList.getRegistro().size()];
        nemotecnico = new TextView[sitesList.getNemotecnico().size()];
        variacion = new TextView[sitesList.getVariacion().size()];
        precio = new TextView[sitesList.getPrecio().size()];


        /** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */
        for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getRegistro().size(); i++) {

            variacion[i] = new TextView(this);
            variacion[i].setText(sitesList.getVariacion().get(i));

            nemotecnico[i] = new TextView(this);
            nemotecnico[i].setText(sitesList.getNemotecnico().get(i));

            precio[i]  = new TextView(this);
            precio[i].setText(sitesList.getPrecio().get(i)); 

           ((ViewGroup)layout).addView(nemotecnico[i]);
           ((ViewGroup)layout).addView(variacion[i]);
           ((ViewGroup)layout).addView(precio[i]);

        }   
        /** Set the layout view to display */
       setContentView(layout);

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a ListView out of it with a custom row that has the header and the 4 other TextViews in a GridLayout in each custom row. Then you can write a custom Adapter to fill them in when you override the getView() method.

This is a nice demo: http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/customizing-android-listview-item-layout/

Your custom row would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView1" />

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView5" />

</GridLayout>
```